# How to change default port in a lowdefy app

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform

does anyone know how to actually change the default port (3000) to for example 8080 in a lowdefy app? Does anyone have a experience in deploying lowdefy app to Google Cloud App Engine?

I can't really find anything useful in the lowdefy docs. Would appreciate the help thanks

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.